# Unzip failing due to long name in zipped folder

Tags: r, connection, zip, rgdal

I want to be able to read and edit spatial SQlite tables that are downloaded from a server. These come compressed.

These zip files have a folder in them that contains information about the model that has been run as the name of the folder, and as such these can sometimes be quite long.

When this folder name gets too long, unziping the folder fails. I ultimately dont need to unzip the file. But i seem to get the same error when I use unz within readOGR.

I cant think of how to recreate a replicate able example but I can give an example of a path that works and one that doesnt.

Works:
"S:\3_Projects\CRC00001\4699-12103\scenario_initialised model\performance_assessment.sqlite"

4699-12103 is the zip file name
and "scenario_initialised model" is the offending subfolder

Fails:
""S:\3_Projects\CRC00001\4699-12129\scenario_tree_canopy_7, number_of_trees_0, roads_False, compliance_75, year_2030, nrz_cover_0.6, green_roofs_0\performance_assessment.sqlite""

4699-12103 is the zip file name
and "scenario_tree_canopy_7, number_of_trees_0, roads_False, compliance_75, year_2030, nrz_cover_0.6, green_roofs_0" is the offending subfolder

The code would work in a similar fashion to this.

```
list_zips <- list.files(pattern = "*.zip", recursive = TRUE, include.dirs = TRUE)

unzip(zipfile = paste(getwd(),"/",list_zips[i],sep = ""),
                    exdir=substr(paste(getwd(),"/",list_zips[i],sep = ""),1,nchar(paste(getwd(),"/",list_zips[i],sep = ""))-4))
```

But I would prefer to directly be able to load the spatial file in without unzipping. Such as:

```
sq_path <- unzip(list_zips[i], list=TRUE)[2,1]
temp <- unz(paste(getwd(),"/",list_zips[i],sep = ""),sq_path)
vectorImport <- readOGR(dsn=temp, layer="micro_climate_grid")
```

Any help would be appreciated! Tim